# Prevent variable value becoming zero despite refreshing activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, refresh

I am using language changing option via top right corner menu click option.
The problem is, when i select a language , activity refreshes. It causes me two problems.

Code for changing language is as following

```
    case R.id.English:

            Locale myLocale1 = new Locale("en");
            Resources res1 = getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm1 = res1.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf1 = res1.getConfiguration();
            conf1.locale = myLocale1;
            res1.updateConfiguration(conf1, dm1);
            Intent refresh1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(refresh1);

            // Do nothing for now
            return true;
```

First of all, it takes me begin of the activity.
Secondly,

```
long timeStart=System.currentTimeMillis();
```

this timeStart becomes zero. But I want the value at first when my app begins. Moreover, other variable values become zero too.

Now how can I prevent value of "timeStart" and other variable becoming zero but language change option will take effect?

Answer (score -1):

i think you have to just change the mechanism to refresh activity like this

```
private void restartActivity() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```